# why intval(042) return result 34? how it works?

Tags: php

I try understand how intval() works and one of the example is intval(042) = 34. As I know the default base is 10, so why it returns 34 instead 42. What role the zero playing in this example?

```
echo intval(042); //34
echo intval(42); //42
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The leading 0 tells php to interpret it as [octal/base 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

`042` in octal is `34` in decimal.

You can find a list of other formats for integers in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: To explain for those that don't understand base-8, the "tens" column is really "eights". Therefore `(4 * 8) + 2 = 34`, the parenthesis representing the "eights" column.

Answer (score 6):

Numbers prefixed with `0` are considered octal numbers (base 8). `0428 = 3410`

In fact, this has nothing to do with `intval`. If you just write `echo 042;` you'll get `34`.

Similarly, you can also write numbers in hexadecimal. `echo 0xff;` gives `255`.

And, as of PHP 5.4, you can even write numbers in binary: `echo 0b1001;` gives `9`.

Comment: +1 for the info about binary in 5.4+ didn't know that, neat.

Answer (score 1):

because 0 before a number mean that this number is a octal number ,try to convert 42 form octal to decimal it will give you 34

i hope this help you,